# Uninstall Npgsql 3.1.6

Tags: windows, uninstallation, npgsql

This is a critical issue for me.
How to uninstall NpgSql 3.1.6 from the Windows machine, as I am unable to find a way to do it. Kindly help me to uninstall NPGSQL 3.1.6.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Npgsql as a nuget package, then there's nothing to "uninstall" - simply remove the dependency on it.

If you installed Npgsql via the MSI installer, you should be able to uninstall it as a regular Windows program (i.e. Uninstall a program).

If for some reason you can't uninstall with MSI, you can:

1. Remove Npgsql from your GAC by running `gacutil /u Npgsql` from Developer Command Prompt for VS2015.
2. Remove Npgsql from your machine.config (`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[version]\config\machine.config` for 64-bit, `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\config\machine.config` for 32-bit).